# General solution to simultaneous equations - Resistors in parallel

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I'm designing a system that uses a grid of resistive sensors, and I'm having trouble figuring out the solution to a set of equations that is the output of this system. I haven't done serious maths for a long time, so go easy on me!

The equations are:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R3}+\frac{1}{R4}...\frac{1}{R_x}+\frac{1}{A}}}{R1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R3}+\frac{1}{R4}...\frac{1}{R_x}+\frac{1}{A}}}=Y_1$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R3}+\frac{1}{R4}...\frac{1}{R_x}+\frac{1}{A}}}{R2+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R3}+\frac{1}{R4}...\frac{1}{R_x}+\frac{1}{A}}}=Y_2$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R4}...\frac{1}{R_x}+\frac{1}{A}}}{R3+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R4}...\frac{1}{R_x}+\frac{1}{A}}}=Y_3$$

$$...$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R3}...\frac{1}{R_{x-1}}+\frac{1}{A}}}{R_x+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R3}...\frac{1}{R_{x-1}}+\frac{1}{A}}}=Y_x$$

With the number of equations equal to the number of RR terms (so for $R1−R4$, there would actually be $4$ equations). $A$ is a constant, and $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ etc are all known.

I have no idea really how to begin solving this. I need a general solution because the values will be constantly changing over time. Does anyone have any pointers?

edit: put back A

edit: here is a diagram of the circuit that these equations represent.

[image: circuit diagram]

$Y1$ is the output voltage with the top switch connected to +V and the others connected to 0V. $Y2$ is the output voltage with the second switch connected to +V and the others connected to 0V. $Y3$ is the output voltage with the third switch connected to +V and the others connected to 0V, etc.

Actually, more exactly, Y is the output voltage divided by +v, to give a ratio. The circuit can be simulated using this [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Ar%20144%20144%20192%20144%200%201000%0Ar%20144%2080%20192%2080%200%201000%0Ar%20144%20208%20192%20208%200%201000%0Av%20-48%20224%20-48%2064%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20-48%20224%20-48%20304%200%0Aw%20256%2080%20192%2080%200%0AS%20144%20208%2096%20208%200%200%20false%200%202%0AS%20144%20144%2096%20144%200%200%20false%200%202%0AS%20144%2080%2096%2080%200%201%20false%200%202%0Aw%20192%2080%20192%20144%200%0Aw%20192%20144%20192%20208%200%0Aw%2096%2064%2032%2064%200%0Aw%20-48%2064%2032%2064%200%0Aw%2032%2064%2032%20128%200%0Aw%2032%20128%2032%20192%200%0Aw%2032%20192%2096%20192%200%0Aw%2096%20128%2032%20128%200%0Ag%2048%20240%2048%20288%200%0Aw%2096%20224%2048%20224%200%0Aw%2048%20224%2048%20240%200%0Aw%2096%20160%2048%20160%200%0Aw%2048%20160%2048%20224%200%0Aw%2096%2096%2048%2096%200%0Aw%2048%2096%2048%20160%200%0Ar%20256%20160%20256%20208%200%201000%0Ag%20256%20208%20256%20288%200%0Aw%20256%2080%20256%20160%200%0AO%20256%20160%20336%20160%200%0Ax%20174%2062%20197%2065%204%2018%20R1%0Ax%20158%20124%20181%20127%204%2018%20R2%0Ax%20162%20186%20185%20189%204%2018%20R3%0Ax%20299%20147%20315%20150%204%2024%20Y%0Ax%20272%20218%20284%20221%204%2018%20A%0A).

Comment: There seems to be an $R_x$ term in there too, what is that?

Comment: I just mean that there can be more $R$ terms (with more equations in the same form)

Comment: To me it seems like you want to change variables. If the $A$ term were not there, I would introduce $S_i=\left ( \sum_{j \neq i} R_j^{-1} \right )^{-1}$ and $S=\left ( \sum_j R_j^{-1} \right )^{-1}$, then $R_i=(S^{-1}-S_i^{-1})^{-1}$ so it becomes easy to rewrite the equations only in terms of $S_i$ and $S$. Specifically you'd have $\frac{S_i}{(S^{-1}-S_i^{-1})^{-1}+S_i}=Y_i$. Then you have the "consistency requirement" that $nS^{-1}=\sum_i S_i^{-1}$, which is now $n+1$ equations in $n+1$ unknowns. This trick doesn't quite work as is with the $A$ term there, though, or at least I think so...

Comment: @Ian Hmm, it looks like A can actually be removed by changing the electronic system. Does that make it possible?

Comment: Oh, sadly without A it looks like there isnt enough information

Comment: Well, without $A$ you can rearrange the equations to solve for the result in terms of $S$ and then plug all of that into the equation to $S$; the result in that case is $S_i=\frac{S}{(1-Y_i)}$ if $Y_i \neq 1$. to solve for $S$ and then back-substitute to find $S_i$, and then finally back-substitute to find $R_i$. But I'm not sure how to fix the issue with the $A$ in this framework.

Comment: The problem is that without A, you only get relative information about the values of the resistors

Comment: What does this network look like? It might be easier to deduce the resistances a different way from direct calculation.

Comment: @amd added diagram

Comment: But, according to the diagram, if one switch is connected to power and all other to ground, and resistance are the same, there is no difference as to which switch is on .

Comment: Well in that example all the Rs are the same, but in other cases they could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;\dfrac{1}{R} = \dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}+\dfrac{1}{R_3}+\ldots+ \dfrac{1}{R_x}+\dfrac{1}{A}\;$ then the equations can be written as:

$$\require{cancel}
\dfrac{\;\;\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R}-\dfrac{1}{R_k}}\;\;}{\;\;R_k+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R}-\dfrac{1}{R_k}}\;\;} = Y_k \;\;\iff\;\; R_k\left(\dfrac{1}{R}-\cancel{\dfrac{1}{R_k}}\right)+\cancel{1}=\frac{1}{Y_k} \;\;\iff \dfrac{1}{R_k} = \dfrac{Y_k}{R} \tag{1}
$$

Summing up $\,(1)\,$ for $\,k=1,2,\ldots x\,$ gives $\,\dfrac{1}{R}-\dfrac{1}{A}= \dfrac{Y}{R}\,$ where $\displaystyle\,Y = \sum_{k=1}^x Y_k\,$, so $\,R = (1-Y)A\,$ then it follows from $\,(1)\,$ that $\,R_k=\dfrac{(1-Y)A}{Y_k}\,$.

Comment: Yesssss thats right! This will make resistive sensor matrices much easier